# CSS - How to make a full height layout with 2 columns from 3 content blocks

Tags: css, grid

[image]

I'm dealing with issue on desktop, where I want both "columns" to be at full height, classic case.

The issue is, on mobile, the left column then goes in between the content to the right, so I can't simply wrap the right side into a column.

The only way I can think of is to fake the background as a pseudo class on the container surrounding the layout. Which will work, but I find it sloppy. Flexbox is out of question since I can't make it 2 proper columns, I'm not sure if grid allows for completely random height (since it can't be just defined, it has to follow the side of content), and I have no ideas besides that.

There is a lot of data in each one of these blocks, so I really don't want to duplicate anything just for this purpose. Is there a way to do this without javascript? For context, it's for e-shop: https://un59puoovusg-chytapustcz-tpltest.simpliashop.cz/Pruty/ You have filters on the left side and content on the right side.

Comment: Hello. You should make a minimally reproducible example here, or show html and css. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask